# How these type of TSA locks are fixed onto luggage?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have examined a TSA lock on my luggage which is this type:

[image]

This is very easy to apply onto a (hardshell) luggage, only 2 screws are needed.

So, to apply this lock onto a suitcase, you have to drill two holes and you are good to go.

However many modern and high quality cases are having these slim kind locks:

[image]

I nowhere found any draft, blueprint or disassembly video about this kind of locks.

And I'm very much interested on how these locks are fixed to the luggage?

I hope someone has the answer and this is the good forum to post this.

Comment: most likely rivets ... everything else is attached that way

Comment: Hm. And if rivets are used, they should be visible from this perspective, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Daniel not if they are "pop-rivets" which can be installed from one side & terminate internally

Comment: If you're concerned about security then the lock is probably worthless - however it is attached. A ballpoint pen pushed through the zipper will probably open the zip. The only thing the lock will do is prevent someone zipping closed again.

Comment: I'm not concerned about security, I'm just curious on how are these locks attached to the luggage :)